# Duplicate entry on a preg_match php

Tags: php, regex

i'm new on stackoverflow and I have a problem with a preg_match

```
var_dump($_POST);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

            if (preg_match("/^.00$/",$key)){
                echo "$value <br>";
            }
            if (preg_match("/^.q[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$/",$key)){
                echo "$value <br>";
            }
            if (preg_match("/^.r[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$/",$key)){
                echo "$value <br>";
            }
```

And I get this :

```
  array(10) {
 [100]=> string(7) "qsdfsdf" 
["c1"]=> string(1) "1" 
["1q1"]=> string(10) "1question1" 
["1r1"]=> string(9) "1reponse1" 
[200]=> string(12) "dqsfqsdfdfqs"
["c2"]=> string(1) "2"
["2q1"]=> string(10) "2question1"
["2r1"]=> string(9) "2reponse1" 
["2q2"]=> string(10) "2question2" 
["2r2"]=> string(9) "1reponse2" }
qsdfsdf
qsdfsdf
qsdfsdf
1question1
1reponse1
dqsfqsdfdfqs
2question1
2reponse1
2question2
1reponse2
```

I don't understand why there is a duplicate entry for the first entry of the array

Comment: `100` matches each of your RegExes...

Comment: Exactly. You should use `if` and `else if`.

Comment: A stupid error, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should use if else statement . there are some string matches in every string .